# I want to retrive updated_at from database and Store as H:M:S in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am making chapters that has to be unlocked after every 24 hrs so I want to retrieve updated_at and store in Javascript variable and then I want to disable the href links after every 24 hrs.

I have tried the logic but it didn't worked

```
<script>
      var date = new Date();
      date = {{$updated_at[0]}};
      console.log(date);
</script>

@if(coins[0] == 0)
<a href="" class="disabled">
<a href="" class="disabled">
<a href="" class="disabled">
@endif
```

Comment: You should store `updated_at` in cookie

Comment: but if the user deletes the cookie So?

Comment: if that, you should store user token include `User IP` in your database and check it every time user access page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to do that in order to release chapters based on time ... you can do simple date calculations to do so.

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$end = end date;
$length = $end->diffInDays($now);
```

And based on that you can release how many chapters your user should see